# Tab bar - more menu table view, navigation class doesn't call

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Hierarchy of my Storyboard is:

```
                                    -- Nav Controller -> First Controller
                                   /-- Nav Controller2 -> Second Controller
                                  /--- Nav Controller3 -> Third Controller
                                 /---- Nav Controller4 -> Fourth Controller
HomeScreen ---> TabBarController ----- Nav Controller5 -> Fifth Controller
                                 \---- Nav Controller6 -> Sixth Controller
```

The problem is: Navigation to **Nav Controller6** is located on More table view. **Nav Controller 6** has its own custom class extend from NavigationController. It has some methods like "viewDidLoad", "viewWillAppear" and so on. But it doesn't call from more table view.
The view redirects correctly, and navigation works fine but methods are not get called.

What should I look for? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: have you forgot to set delegates? what is the type of 6th controller?

Comment: It is a ProfileUpdateNavigationController: UINavigationController - but to where should I set the delegate? It's an independent class so it should go directly to the Controller. Where should I set delegates?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved ??? I am seeing the same behavior with my custom UINavigationController subclass

Comment: As far as I remember I called the controller manually